# Codeigniter 2.1, PHP - combining two functions into one

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have following two function, and I would like to know, is there any way I can combine them into one.

```
function galerija_get_all(){
$q = $this->db->get('galerija');
return $q = $q->result_array();
}

function galerija_get_all_slike(){
$q = $this->db->get('slike');
return $q = $q->result_array();
}
```

And in my view file I have this code:

```
<?php foreach ($galerija as $gal): ?>
<figure>
<?php foreach ($galerija_slike as $img): ?>
<?php if ($gal['id_galerija'] == $img['galerija_id']): ?>

<?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
<img src="" >
<figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Is it possible (and if it is, how) this two codes?

Answer (score 5):

You could always do this..

```
function galerija_get_all($type){
    $q = $this->db->get($type);
    return $q->result_array();
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
falerija_get_all('slike');
```

or

```
falerija_get_all('galerija');
```

Comment: I now have solution for the first part :). Any ideas for the second part of the problem?

Comment: This is late, but you mean looping out the second part? Sure that's not a problem however I provided you with only the function this way you could implement in into any template as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can store both results in an array and then return the array as a single result.

```
function get_all(){
   $galerija = $this->db->get('galerija')->result_array();
   $slike = $this->db->get('slike')->result_array();

   $result = array('galerija'=> $galerija,
                   'slike'   => $slike);
   return $result;
}
```

Then in the view you can do this

```
<?php foreach ($result['galerija'] as $gal): ?>
<figure>
<?php foreach ($result['slike'] as $img): ?>
<?php if ($gal['id_galerija'] == $img['galerija_id']): ?>

<?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
<img src="" >
<figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
<?php endforeach ?>
```